# CGIプログラムの引数を環境変数で渡すのはどうしてですか？

Tags: c, cgi

webサーバーの実装を勉強中です。forkしてexecveでCGIプログラムを実行しようと思っています。
そのCGIプログラムへの引数は環境変数QUERY_STRINGに設定し、getenvで受け取るという認識です。

execveの第二引数ではなくQUERY_STRINGで渡すのは何故なのでしょうか？
どういった経緯でこの様に規格が策定されたのでしょうか？

Comment: 774RRさん同様、経緯は分かりませんが、この辺の仕様書 [RFC 3875 - The Common Gateway Interface (CGI) Version 1.1 日本語訳](https://tex2e.github.io/rfc-translater/html/rfc3875.html) を読み解くと何か分かるかもしれません。

Comment: query_stringの項は一応読んでいたのですが、他のところもちゃんと読んでみようと思います。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

世界で二番目に開発された[NCSA httpd](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/NCSA_HTTPd)でCGIが導入されました。今や当時のサイトは残っていませんが、INTERNET ARCHIVEに保存されていました。[1997年12月10日のCGI Command line options (http://hoohoo.ncsa.uiuc.edu/cgi/cl.html)](http://web.archive.org/web/19971210170913/http://hoohoo.ncsa.uiuc.edu/cgi/cl.html)には

> The command line is only used in the case of an ISINDEX query. It is not used in the case of an HTML form or any as yet undefined query type. The server should search the query information (the QUERY_STRING environment variable) for a non-encoded = character to determine if the command line is to be used, if it finds one, the command line is not to be used. This trusts the clients to encode the = sign in ISINDEX queries, a practice which was considered safe at the time of the design of this specification.

と書かれていて、 `=` を含む `QUERY_STRING` の場合は環境変数を使用し、含まない場合はコマンドライン引数で渡すとされています。（あくまで当時の記述です）

Comment: ありがとうございます。昔は=が含まれているかどうかで動作に違いがあったということなんでしょうか・・・。質問時に色々理由を考えていたのですが、サーバー側でURIをchar **argvにパースするのが面倒だとか、コマンドライン引数受け取れない言語があるのかなとか、コマンドライン引数の数の上限に到達することがあるのかなーとか、あまり関係なさそうな気がしてきました。まだ理解が浅い部分が多々あるので、もう少し勉強してから読み直してみたいと思います。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

経緯までは知らんけど CGI の argc / argv はフツーに指定できるっス。

[CGI の仕様 - とほほ](https://www.tohoho-web.com/wwwcgi3.htm)

実際ウチの部内サーバーの test-cgi でちゃんと動いたっス。`http://10.10.10.10/cgi-bin/test-cgi?ab%22b+c%23d` を開くと`argc is 2 argv is a\"b c#d` と表示されたっス。

Comment: rgvでも受け取れるんですね。まだ座学しかしていなかったので、正確に質問できる段階に達していなかったかもしれないです。もう少し勉強してからまた来たいと思います。回答ありがとうございました。